# How to Know Model Type using AWS Java SDK for Machine Learning

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, machine-learning, aws-sdk

I am using AWS Java SDK to generate RealTime Predictions. To get the output of prediction i need to know what kind of machine learning model is being used is it `binary` , `regression` or `multiclass`. I have only the model id which i can use to locate model.Is there any API or some other way through which i can know the model type in my application.

I have searched through the documentation but haven't found anything that suits my requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the model type by calling the [GetMLModel](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/machine-learning/latest/APIReference/API_GetMLModel.html) API.

```java
AmazonMachineLearningClient client = ...;

GetMLModelRequest request = new GetMLModelRequest().withMLModelId("...");
client.getMLModel(request).getMLModelType();
```